# Parse unknown JSON key with Moshi

Tags: android, json, kotlin, moshi

I'm trying to parse a JSON I know almost nothing about.

Example of a JSON response

```
{
    "response": {
       "content":{
            "xxxxxx": "xxxxx",
            "xxxxx": "xxxxxx",
            ...... indeterminate times
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to create an adapter, but nothing works :

```java
@FromJson
fun fromJson(json: Map<String, String>): MyResponse {
    Log.d("JSON", json.toString())
    return MyResponse(...)
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this with Moshi? If so, what should I do?